# UICollectionView with cells containing UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Are there any restrictions on using UITableViews within the cells of a UICollectionView?

I've tried to find some sample projects that do this, but haven't had any luck

Comment: I'm currently working on a project with a table view, that contains a collection view in each cell, which contains a view controller in each cell, which may sometimes contain a table view. We call it the InceptionViewController...

Answer (score 4):

Here's one gotcha you need to be aware of. If your collection view cell contains a table view,  and you tap on the cell (rather than the table view) then by default the collection view sets itself to highlighted (which, for a standard cell, does nothing). However, in the course of this, it also sets every cell in the table to highlighted, which is terrible, but sort of expected. If you think about it, a table cell does the same thing - all of the cell's subviews, if they respond to `setHiglighted`, will have that message passed to them. This is how the text of the labels in a cell change colour upon highlighting.

You can work around this by preventing highlighting of cells in the collection view's delegate.

Comment: Return NO on:
-(BOOL) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1):

No hard technical restrictions that I'd be aware of. `UITableView`s within `UITableView`s are possible, and `UICollectionView`s are quite similar from the programming logic point of view.

However, there  can be a huge impact on performance with scrolling in either your collection view or your table view.

First. You'd need to carefully code to avoid any superficial calls to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` methods. Make sure you thoroughly understand the logic behind those calls if you attempt to use reusable cells in either your collection view or table view before starting that adventure.

Second. If both components are scrollable, there is a concurrency issue of the panGestureRecognizers of the two view controllers in the hierarchy, which you have to resolve yourself.

Search for implementations of `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView` and vice versa, too, to get a feeling for the problems that can arise.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to find some sample projects that do this

I don't think you need a sample project -- just do it.

`-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is supposed to return a `UICollectionViewCell`. UITableView doesn't inherit from that class, so to make use a table in a collection view you'd need to create a UICollectionViewCell subclass that contains a UITableView. I don't see a problem with doing that other than possible performance problems. If you're going to have just one or two cells in the collection view visible at a time, it's probably not a problem. I'd avoid trying to do something like a grid with a dozen tiny tables, though. Try it and see how it goes.